# Display a div element between a group of list items without altering the HTML (to keep it semantic)

Tags: html, css

I have a list of products, except the blue-colored one.

The blue is an information block from the company which is not related at all to the product listed.

[image]

So logically, to keep it semantic, I'm writing it like this.

```
<ul>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
</ul>
<div> <!-- the blue colored box here --> </div>
```

However with this arrangement, the blue-colored box will be displayed after the products, while the design requires me to put it between the products.

Is it possible to do this design semantically, without doing crazy stuff like using `position: absolute`?

Comment: Have the rest of products mandatorily be a list? I think you can also do them with divs and just display your blue div in the third position.

Comment: @Error404 That wouldn't be semantic, because the blue div isn't supposed to be a part of that list. The challenging part here is making the design possible while keeping the HTML semantic...

Comment: If you put `float:left` on the li elements and probably on the ul too you may be able to pull off what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its possible just add `float: right` to `div` and place `div` before `ul` in HTML

```css
ul, li, body, html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
li {
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
div {
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div> <!-- the blue colored box here --> </div>
<ul>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the `div` after the `ul`? Since before the list is a `<h2>`, so it would make more sense if the structure has the list first and the div after.

Comment: @deathlock I am not sure about that.

Comment: @deathlock: This will be as close of a compromise as you can get without shoehorning the div into the ul where it doesn't belong. If you can afford to replace the div with an aside, you can probably make an excuse for having it between the h2 and the ul.

Answer (score 2):

Although not as semantically correct as your HTML, maybe this is an acceptable compromise:

Position the blue info box last on the list. It will never appear between any product items in the source. It will take a permanent position at the end.

Then, use the flex `order` property to re-position it anywhere among the list items *only on the screen*.

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    flex: 0 0 30%;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li:first-child  { order: -3; }
li:nth-child(2) { order: -2; }
li:last-child   { order: -1; background-color: aqua; }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- the blue colored box here --> </li>
</ul>
```

From the spec:

> [**5.4. Display Order: the `order` property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#order-property)
>
> Flex items are, by default, displayed and laid out in the same order as they appear in the source document. The 
>   `order` property can be used to change this ordering.
>
> The `order` property controls the order in which children of a flex container appear within the flex container, by assigning them to ordinal groups. It takes a single integer value, which specifies which ordinal group the flex item 
>   belongs to.

The initial `order` value for all flex items is 0. Only the visual display is affected; the DOM is unaltered.

Answer (score 1):

If flex is okay to be used for you, you may insert the `div` into a last `li` *(or just use the last li)*, **so it can be part of the flexbox**.

From there, uou can use `order` to set your box on third position:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order
>   example:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
li {
  width: 33%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  /* reset from list-item */
  /* demo */
  min-height: 75px;
  order: 2;
}
li:nth-child(1),
li:nth-child(2) {
  order: -1;
}
li:last-of-type {
  order: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
/* extra demo purpose */

/* center li content ? */

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
/* give a number to each box to see where they stand */

ul {
  counter-reset: lis;
}
li:before {
  counter-increment: lis;
  content: counter(lis);
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>-- product goes here --></li>
  <li>-- product goes here --></li>
  <li>-- product goes here --></li>
  <li>-- product goes here --></li>
  <li>-- product goes here --></li>
  <li>
    <div>-- the blue colored box here --></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Else the float position would be what you need setting div ahead in the flow

If elements have a known size, then **`absolute`** and either :

1. float + pseudo
2. or flex + pseudo + order

could also be an option, but i would not recommend it at all, since many thing can break it and let content overflow ..

Answer (score -2):

Simple solution:

```
<ul>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- the blue colored box here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
    <li> <!-- product goes here --> </li>
</ul>
```

Instead of just writing a separate div, also if it requires special function just add different class to the rest of the list elements.

Comment: To be fair, it *is* pretty simple to just disregard semantics altogether. But if you're going to do that, better a set of semantically meaningless divs, than to pretend that div is part of the list when it is not.